# sqlite error when calling a function in the shell

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am getting the error:

```
builtins.NameError: name 'sqlite3' is not defined
```

on the line

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
```

Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def run_query(db, q, args=None):
    """(str, str, tuple) -> list of tuple
    Return the results of running query q with arguments args on
    database db."""

    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # execute the query with the given args passed
    # if args is None, we have only a query
    if args is None:
        cur.execute(q)
    else:
        cur.execute(q, args)

    results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return results


 def get_course_instructors(db, course):
    '''Return the Course number, sections and instructors for the given course 
      number.'''
    return (run_query(db, '''SELECT CourseNumber, sections, instructors WHERE
    course = ?''', (course)))
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say you need to `import sqlite3`. If you don't have sqlite3 installed, `pip install sqlite3`. And you still need the `import sqlite3`.

Comment: I fixed it, but now I get this error. cur.execute(q, args)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: CourseNumber

Comment: This is sqlite telling you that a column you're referring to in the database table does not exist. It's possible that one of the columns in the query (CourseNumber, sections, instructors) is misspelled. Perhaps the case of CourseNumber is not correct. Firefox has a plugin you can use to view the sqlite database tables and columns to determine whether this is the problem.

Comment: But the instruction says return the course number. Does it make a difference if I use uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: In looking at your SQL query, it isn't correct anyway. You need to ask it to look in a table. So it should look something like `SELECT CourseNumber, sections, instructors FROM courses WHERE course = ?`. And I arbitrarily assumed the table name is courses. Note also that the `WHERE course = ?` clause implies there IS a *course* column in the same table.

Comment: Yes, its under a table name courses, so how do I fix this?

Comment: At this point, read up on SQL -- do a search. SQL is your problem. Not python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3 # make sure you have this

def get_course_instructors(db, course):
'''Return the Course number, sections and instructors for the given course 
number.'''
```

Get course code, sections and instructors from Courses table, assuming your variable names are "CourseNumber, sections, instructors" in the Courses table.

```
return run_query(db, '''SELECT Course, Section, Name FROM Courses WHERE course = ?''', (course,))
```

Make sure you have a comma after (course) in the return statement.

A test case would look like this.

```
get_course_instructors('exams.db', 'AFSA01H3F')
[('AFSA01H3F', 'LEC01', 'S. Rockel')]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160303/discussion-on-answer-by-cboost-sqlite-error-when-calling-a-function-in-the-shell).